# Is there a more efficient way of retrieving batches from a hdf5 dataset?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, hdf5, h5py

I have a dataclass for Pytorch dataloading. It retrieves items from a hdf5 archive (150k samples) before I feed this into a dataloader and train a small one hidden layer autoencoder. However, when I try to train my network, nothing happens, there is no GPU utilization. I am using, 4 CPUs and 2 GPUs to start off with.

My batch size is 128 and I use 8 workers when I start training.

I have also followed Pytorchs dataparallel tutorial. Below is my code for the hdf5 dataclass.

```
import torch.multiprocessing as mp
mp.set_start_method('fork') 

from torch.utils import data
import h5py
import time

class Features_Dataset(data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, file_path, phase):
        self.file_path = file_path
        self.archive = None
        self.phase = phase 
        with h5py.File(file_path, 'r', libver='latest', swmr=True) as f:
           self.length = len(f[(self.phase) + '_labels'])


    def _get_archive(self):
        if self.archive is None:
            self.archive = h5py.File(self.file_path, 'r', libver='latest', swmr=True)
            assert self.archive.swmr_mode
        return self.archive


    def __getitem__(self, index):
        archive = self._get_archive()
        label = archive[str(self.phase) + '_labels']
        datum = archive[str(self.phase) + '_all_arrays']
        path = archive[str(self.phase) + '_img_paths']

        return datum[index], label[index], path[index]

    def __len__(self):
        return self.length

    def close(self):
        self.archive.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    train_dataset = Features_Dataset(file_path= "featuresdata/train.hdf5", phase= 'train')
    trainloader = data.DataLoader(train_dataset, num_workers=8, batch_size=1)
    print(len(trainloader))
    myStart = time.time()
    for i, (data, label, path) in enumerate(trainloader):
        print(path)
```

This is my class for the autoencoder:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class AutoEncoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_embedded):
        super(AutoEncoder, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(6144, n_embedded))
        self.decoder = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(n_embedded, 6144))

    def forward(self, x):
        encoded = self.encoder(x)
        decoded = self.decoder(encoded)

        return encoded, decoded
```

This is how I initialize the model:

```
device = torch.device("cuda") 
    # Initialize / load checkpoint
    model = AutoEncoder(2048)
    if torch.cuda.device_count() > 1:
        print("Let's use", torch.cuda.device_count(), "GPUs!")
    model= nn.DataParallel(model) 
    model.to(device)
    criterion = nn.MSELoss()
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(),weight_decay=1e-5)
```

I make sure that my inputs are put into the device too.

Could the speed of retrieving the batches be the problem? In regards to the hdf5 Features Dataset class, I am attempting to lazily load the hdf5 dataset without using `__init__` however, I think maybe calculating the length of the dataset may be the issue...

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be the bottleneck caused by the lazy loading. You can try to load all the data at **init** of the dataloader (if you have enough resources). Then, at **getitem** just return the datum[index], label[index], path[index] from already prepared lists. Hope it helps. Good luck!